# Docker private registry on localhost fails to retrieve via http

Tags: docker, docker-registry, microk8s

I have setup Docker and microk8s running on Ubuntu WSL. I have pushed a demoapp to private registry running on localhost:5000 and when I try to deploy this demo app image on kubernetes I get imagepull fail stating below error  when I describe the pod,

```
  Normal   Pulling    18s (x2 over 33s)  kubelet            Pulling image "localhost:5000/demoapp:latest"
  Warning  Failed     18s (x2 over 32s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "localhost:5000/demoapp:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "localhost:5000/demoapp:latest": failed to resolve reference "localhost:5000/demoapp:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://localhost:5000/v2/demoapp/manifests/latest": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
  Warning  Failed     18s (x2 over 32s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    2s (x2 over 31s)   kubelet            Back-off pulling image "localhost:5000/demoapp:latest"
  Warning  Failed     2s (x2 over 31s)   kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

I have perused through quite a few posts about this specific error and most of them lead to either daemon.json not having insecure registry value included or docker not restarted, I have tried both of those but it doesnt seem to help. Any pointers is much appreciated as I have met a wall to things I could try to get this resolved.

I have created the registry with below commands and I am able to query registry both on the shell (via curl) as well as via a browser (albeit with http only) and both localhost and 127.0.0.1 works just fine for :5000/v2/_catalog

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
docker tag demoapp:latest localhost:5000/demoapp
docker push localhost:5000/demoapp
```

my docker info show as below:

```
# docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 4
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 3
 Images: 6
 Server Version: 20.10.12
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version:
 runc version:
 init version:
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 12.38GiB
 Name: ADUMMYNAME
 ID: BGDY:B54J:7YV6:3GRJ:6YPU:HO5R:ABGC:I2MC:I4MK:FHBI:B5E6:RU6L
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  localhost:5000
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_iops_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_iops_device support
```

My daemon.json looks as below, I have tried both localhost as well as 127.0.0.1, it seem to make no difference, I have made sure to restart docker on each attempt that I tried.

```
cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
 {
        "insecure-registries" : ["localhost:5000"]
 }
```

Comment: With the various developer k8s installs I've used (minikube, k3s, kind), localhost to them refers to the kubernetes node running in a container or VM, not the localhost of your host.

Comment: @BMitch: Thank you for your response. I have my kubernetes node and Docker running on same WSL2 host, during the image deployment the error seems to complain only about http and https, for some reason the insecure-registry is not taking effect. I verified that it is not address resolution issue by providing an inaccessible port to which the ImagePull action clearly gives a different error (dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5001: connect: connection refused). Which is why I suspect this is just about http-https. But I am open to try out any suggestions

Comment: Try updating insecure-registries  in %userprofile%\.docker\daemon.json or C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json in your Windows

Comment: @Sriram: I am running Docker on Ubuntu WSL (windows subsytem for linux) which is on top of Windows. This docker is not installed directly on Windows.